# Insert in a Linked List : Bug

Tags: c, algorithm, insert, linked-list

In the code below : Insertion function can't insert m ore than 2 nodes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
int val;
struct node * next;
};

struct node * insertl(struct node * head,int value)
{
   if(head==NULL)
  {
     struct node * temp= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
     temp->val = value;
     temp->next=NULL;
     head=temp; printf("%d",value);
     return head;
 }
 if(head->next==NULL)
 {
    struct node * temp= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->val = value;
    temp->next=NULL;
    head->next = temp; printf("%d",value);
    return head;
 }
 struct node *head1=head;
 while(!head1->next)
 {
    head1=head1->next;
    printf("%d",head1->val);
 }

 struct node * temp= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 temp->val = value;
 temp->next=NULL;
 printf("%d",temp->val-90);
 head1->next = temp;
 return head;
 }

  void print(struct node *head)
{     printf("\n");
   struct node * temp = head;
   while(temp!=NULL)
  {
    printf("%d\t",temp->val);
    temp=temp->next;
   }

 }

int main()
{   struct node * h =NULL;
    h=insertl(h,1);
    h=insertl(h,4);
    h=insertl(h,1);
    h=insertl(h,4);
    print(h);
 }
```

I have used the printf statements in between just to check where code goes wrong.
   Output is showing : 1,4 .Why is the code incorrect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct node *head1=head;
while(!head1->next)
      ^
```

I think you are trying to append to the "end" of the list and you meant `while(head1->next)`.

Comment: thanks a lot for such a quick reply. I feel terrible that was very careless